# How to apply VCL Styles to DLL-based forms in Inno Setup for uninstall? Cannot Import dll

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, vcl-styles, vcl-styles.-utils

I'm trying to add VCL styles (Inno Setup 5.5.6 (a)) for my installer. Style load correctly during the installation, but when I try to uninstall I get an error

> Runtime Error(at-1:0): Cannot Import dll:VclStylesInno.dll.

And I can not uninstall my program.

Does anyone know what I can do?
Thanks for the help

```pascal
#define VCLStylesSkinPath "{localappdata}\VCLStylesSkin"

[Files]
;Install
Source: "VclStylesinno.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "Styles\Auric.vsf"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: dontcopy
;Uninstall
Source: "VclStylesinno.dll"; DestDir: "{#VCLStylesSkinPath}"; \
  Flags: uninsneveruninstall
Source: "Styles\Auric.vsf"; DestDir: "{#VCLStylesSkinPath}"; \
  Flags: uninsneveruninstall

[Code]

{ Import the LoadVCLStyle function from VclStylesInno.DLL }
procedure LoadVCLStyle(VClStyleFile: String);
  external 'LoadVCLStyleA@files:VclStylesInno.dll stdcall setuponly';
procedure LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(VClStyleFile: String);
  external 'LoadVCLStyleA@VclStylesInno.dll stdcall uninstallonly';

{ Import the UnLoadVCLStyles function from VclStylesInno.DLL }
procedure UnLoadVCLStyles;
  external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@files:VclStylesInno.dll stdcall setuponly';
procedure UnLoadVCLStyles_UnInstall;
  external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@VclStylesInno.dll stdcall uninstallonly';
    
function InitializeUninstall: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(ExpandConstant('Styles\Auric.vsf'));
end;

procedure DeinitializeUninstall();
begin
  UnLoadVCLStyles_UnInstall;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying a path to the uninstall copy of the `VclStylesInno.dll`.

This is the correct way:

```pascal
procedure LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(VClStyleFile: String); 
  external 'LoadVCLStyleA@{#VCLStylesSkinPath}\VclStylesInno.dll stdcall uninstallonly';
```

Next time, just follow the official [instructions for uninstalling the VCL Styles for Inno Setup](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-plugins/wiki/Inno-Setup#uninstaller-sample-script).

For more details and maybe even a better solution than the official one, see also [Load external DLL for uninstall process in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36940506/850848).